# Windows 10 IoT (embedded device) Visual Studio 2019 debugging via USB

Tags: c, visual-studio, windows-10, iot, windows-10-universal

I have a headless embedded device with Windows 10 running on it. I want to debug my application on the embedded device, in real time, with Visual Studio 2019 via a USB connection.

I have developer mode setup on both the development machine and the device.

I can debug fine via Ethernet but like I said I want to debug via USB.

On the embedded device in Windows 10 there is a ‘Developer Settings’ and when run there is an option for ‘Developer Mode’ under ‘Use developer features’.
I click on this and it says “Developer mode is turned on. However, remote deployment and Windows Device Portal couldn’t be found in Windows Update, so they’re not available. Error code 0x8024402dc”.

Also on the same settings page there are sections entitled ‘Enable Device Portal’ and ‘Device discovery’. Both of these options are greyed out and I’m pretty sure to get the usb debugging working I need to be able to turn these on. (I do have these turned on the development machine though)

Under the ‘Device Discovery’ option it states: 
“Note: This requires version 1803 of the Windows 10 SDK or later.”

I’ve installed, or least think I’ve installed, the Windows 10 SDK (18362.1.190318-1202.19h1releae_WindowsSDK.iso’ which is supposed to have the ability to turn on these needed options on but does not seem to help.

I also have Visual Studio 2019 Remote debugger running on the device.

I’ve tried both setting up my debug session using either ‘Device’ or ‘Remote Machine’ but nothing connects using the USB cable. I get the following error from Visual Studio:

> “DEP6957: Failed to connect to device '127.0.0.1' using Universal
>   Authentication. Please verify the correct remote authentication mode
>   is specified in the project debug settings. COMException - No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007274D) [0x8007274D].”

Any help would be appreciated.